# How to disable Neo4j message of the day

Tags: configuration, neo4j

I've secured my neo4j setup with SSL certificates, however, I got "Partially encrypted content" warning.

So I checked why, and it turns out Neo4J is calling out to

```
http://assets.neo4j.org/v2/json/neo4jmotd?callback=angular.callbacks._0&count=10?plain=true
```

To get a useless message of the day.
Is there a way to disable it or make it use ssl?